# How to make the view in front of my custom Tab Bar ? Not behind it when appears?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I need to my second view that I want to appear after button pressed displayed in front of Tab Bar, not behind as it is.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
   
    @State private var tabSelection = 1
    @EnvironmentObject var timerModel: TimerModel
    
    
    var body: some View
    {
        TabView(selection: $tabSelection) {
            DashboardView()
                .tag(1)
            TimerView()
                .tag(2)
                .environmentObject(timerModel)
            SettingsView()
                .tag(3)
            
        }
        .overlay(alignment: .bottom)
        {
            CustomTabView(tabSelection: $tabSelection)
        }
   

    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View
    {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(TimerModel())
    }
}
    `

     @ViewBuilder
    func NewTimerView()->some View
    {
        VStack(spacing: 15) {
            Text("Change Timer Settings")
                .font(.title2.bold())
                .foregroundStyle(.black)
                .padding(.top, 10)
           etc content...
}

     NewTimerView()
                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
                    .offset(y : timerModel.addNewTimer ? 0 : 600)
                    .zIndex(timerModel.addNewTimer ? 1 : 0)
            }
            .animation(.easeInOut, value: timerModel.addNewTimer)
```

[image: Bug]

Answer (score 0):

The selected tab is appearing behind the custom tab bar, becuase the tab bar is being shown in an overlay.

Try using a `VStack` as the parent container instead:

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        TabView(selection: $tabSelection) {
            DashboardView()
                .tag(1)
            TimerView()
                .tag(2)
                .environmentObject(timerModel)
            SettingsView()
                .tag(3)

        }
        CustomTabView(tabSelection: $tabSelection)
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing changed when I added VStack there.

Comment: And you took away the overlay?

Comment: Now I lost the capsule shape of TabBar and second view is appeared on top of the tab bar.

Comment: If the second view is appearing on top of the tab bar then it must be forcing its way there. Are you using ```offset``` to move it down, perhaps? As for the missing capsule shape, perhaps it's there but you're not seeing it because the capsule color is the same as the background behind it?  You could try a different color for the base background. For more help, please add more code to the question, I'm just guessing at the implementation here.